# Removing poles in meromorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I was reading Cox's" Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$. This was a result from complex analysis that was often used. I have the following question:

Let $:ℂ→ℂ$ be a meromorphic function with a pole of order  at $=z_0$. Let $g(z)$ be  a meromorphic function $:ℂ→ℂ$, such that $g'(z_0)\neq 0$, then the function $()(()−(_0))^$ holomorphic at $_0$. Is the condition $g'(z_0)\neq 0$ required?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not required.  If $g'(z_0) = 0$, a lower power of $g(z) - g(z_0)$ can be used to make the function holomorphic at $z_0$ (after removing a removable singularity).  Thus if
$g'(z_0) = \ldots = g^{(m-1)}(z_0) = 0$ but $g^{(m)}(z_0) \ne 0$, then $g(z) - g(z_0)$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z_0$, and $(g(z)-g(z_0))^{k}$ has a zero of order $km$ there, so $f(z) (g(z) - g(z_0))^k$ has a removable singularity there if $f$ has a pole of order $\le km$ there.